# Spring Boot + Batch multi module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am building a multi module project with Spring Boot and Batch.

The directory structure currently is:

- core
- web
- batch

**core** contains the domain objects, repositories, services.

**web** contains the Spring Boot app - controllers etc

**batch** contains the Spring Batch app - job configurations etc

**web** and **batch** each have their own context annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and I configure on execution using the `start-class` property eg `-Dstart-class=com.company.web.WebApplication`

The problem comes when including the **core** classes, neither app will launch due to missing bean definitions for the repositories so it sounds like component scanning is not working for the core module.

I have experimented with `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses...` and `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses...` but without luck.

Any ideas what I'm missing or if there is a better way of architecting this?

Comment: Is it a maven multiple project module? is each module properly defined to see each other as dependencies? can you share your pom files.

Comment: I am using `Gradle` because it's 2017 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar structure as you do, and everything works fine. I can assume you could have following problem - packaging of your artifacts: they don't contain dependency of core jar library.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
}
```

Can you check your packaged artifacts? Do they contain core libraries?